# Launch Run with "Create this task with administrative privileges" option

Tags: windows, windows-10, runas, run-dialog

I want to launch the Run dialog with the `Create this task with administrative privileges` option. I am able to do this with Task Manager, but it involves launching Task Manager that I don't want to do. I am going to use AutoHotkey to launch it so I am fine with some scripting if it is required. Also "Most recently used" list is very important for me. So it should work in it.

Here is the screenshot of the Task Manager

[image: Run Dialog].

Comment: Consider doing this from the command line. `SCHTASKS` has many options, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx.

Comment: @root That's not what I want to do